# Heroku Redis cant open connection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, redis, redistogo

I following Ryan Bates tutorial ActionController Live, and deploying app at heroku. All works fine, except events, where Ryan sad that we should reopen the redis connection, and I cant do it. I using RedisToGo to perform redis on heroku.
Here my events controller action:

```
def events
    response.headers["Content-Type"] = "text/event-stream"
    redis = Redis.new(:url => uri)
    redis.psubscribe('messages.*') do |on|
        on.pmessage do |pattern, event, data|
            response.stream.write("event: #{event}\n")
            response.stream.write("data: #{data}\n\n")
        end
    end
    rescue IOError
        logger.info "Stream closed"
    ensure
        redis.quit
        response.stream.close
end
```

Also here redis initializer:

```
uri = URI.parse(ENV["REDISTOGO_URL"])
REDIS = Redis.new(:url => uri)
```

Can someone help me?

**EDIT**

I got all to work just initializing the client using `Redis.new(url: ENV["REDISTOGO_URL"])` instead of parsing the URI in events controller action.

Answer (score 0):

replace this:

```
redis = Redis.new(:url => uri)
redis.psubscribe
```

with this:

```
REDIS.psubscribe
```

anywhere you have 'redis' above, replace with the REDIS global.

Comment: this dont resolve the problem, event doesnt happend, no error occured

Comment: you have that REDIS = Redis.new in your config/initializers somewhere, right?

Comment: Also have this line in create controller action:
REDIS.publish('messages.create', @message.to_json)

Comment: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0
Find this error in server logs, its causes if i dont open the connection in events action